# Clipping complete building/closed polygons only from polygon shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, clip

I have a polygon layer of buildings and a polygon layer of AOI. Now I want to clip only complete/closed polygon that falls within this AOI.

[image: Black boundary is my AOI polygon and the buildings are in green]

As you can see there are certain buildings that have a portion of them within the AOI but I don't want them. I only want complete polygons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, to get the buildings that are completely within your area of interest, in QGIS you only need to:

1. Select the buildings that are completely contained within your area of interest:
2. Start [Select by Location](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-location) (found under *Vector selection* in the the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and under *Vector > Research tools* in the menus)
3. Select your building layer in `Select features from` and the layer with your area of interest in `By comparing to the features from`.
   Check/tick **only** `are within` for `Where the features (geometric predicate)` and then press the <kbd>Run</kbd> button.
   This is what the dialog should look like:

   [image]

   The buildings fully contained within the area of interest will now be selected.
4. Right-click on the building layer in the table of contents and choose *Export > Save Features As*. Make sure that `Save only selected features` is checked/ticked before finishing the export.